# Why am I getting pinching on my mesh?

Tags: modeling

I can't identify the problem here. I know I have a couple of tris there and I know it's a bad practice, but I didn't see a way around it.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: here's the file:

[image]

Comment: I know I have a couple of tris there and I know it's a bad practice, but I didn't see a way around it

Comment: I can't say for certain from just a screenshot, but there may be two vertices in the same location, each connecting only two of the four edges at that location. Have you tried removing doubles?

Comment: @DuaneDibbley Already checked for doubles :/ should I screenshot it from another angle?

Comment: perhaps share your file

Comment: @moonboots I'm new to the site, how do I do that?

Comment: Upload it here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add generated code to your post (not in comment).

Comment: @cgslav alright, did it. I've been trying to make a skyrim sword, but ran into this peculiar problem and I've no idea what's wrong. from whatever angle I look at it, I can't figure it out :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you have one long edge connecting the upper and lower vertices, as well as several shorter edges in the same place.

[image]

Select the long one, and remove it, and the problem will go away.

To select it, you may have to click several times, to alternate between the long one and one of the shorter ones. Once the long one is selected, remove it by pressing <kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>E</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Oooooooh... I was staring at my shape for ages trying to figure it out.. How did you notice it? Was it obvious and I just missed it?

Comment: I simply selected edges one by one and moved them slightly to see what remained and how things were connected. If things had been connected a bit differently, you might have had to rebuild some topology, but in this specific case, removing that edge was enough.

Comment: I appreciate the help! +1

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you get a pinch because of your normals of the mesh. Just recalculate them by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> > *recalculate outside/ inside.*

Comment: Hey, welcome to BSE! While normals are important for many shading artifacts, they're not really the culprit here. If you check in the provided blend you'll find that the problem is not solved by recalculating outside since the subsurf modifier doesn't use them to calculate geometry.